# How to react to scroll down and up?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know the direction of scrolling at the moment of scrolling up or down in the list view.  but I couldn't find a solution.

I tried to use ScrollController to listen to the direction of scrolling for dealing with different work as up and down scrolls. But there is no way to listen to that with ScrollController.
Is there anyone to have dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [`NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html). You will need to wrap your scroll view in that widget and then listen to [`UserScrollNotification`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/ScrollDirection-class.html)s:

```dart
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is UserScrollNotification) {
      if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
        // Handle scroll down.
      } else if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        // Handle scroll up.
      }
    }

    // Returning null (or false) to
    // "allow the notification to continue to be dispatched to further ancestors".
    return null;
  },
  child: ListView(..), // Or whatever scroll view you use.
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I sloved the problem with yours.